# Nested ToManyFields in django-tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I have two `ModelResource`s, `Attack` and `Packet`, related by a ManyToManyField.

This tends to show up with `Packet.attacks` containing 1-3 attacks, and `Attack.packets` containing hundreds of packets.

The way I've been planning to do this is this: each `AttackResource` has an `Attack.packets` attribute that is a link to a the queryset containing `Attack.packets` and where the queryset is nested in `AttackResource`.

i.e.:

```
/api/attack/1/ # contains attribute with URL of /api/attack/1/packets/
/api/attack/1/packets/ # contains all packets where attack with id=1 is in Packet.attacks
```

How can I do this?

I've tried following [cyberdelia's gist](https://gist.github.com/921581) to have nested resources, but going to `/api/attack/1/packets/` doesn't actually contain packets where attack.id is in packet.attacks.

My `ModelResource` class is identical to the gist, and then my other resources are:

```
class AttackResource(ModelResource):
    packets = fields.ToManyField('honeywall.api.PacketResource', 'packets', 'attack')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Attack.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'attack'
```

and

```
class PacketResource(ModelResource):
    attacks = fields.ToManyField('honeywall.api.AttackResource', 'attacks', 'packet')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Packet.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'packet'
        filtering = {
            'attacks': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your AttackResource:

```
def prepend_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/packets%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('get_attacks'), name="api_get_attacks"),
    ]

def get_attacks(self, request, **kwargs):
    try:
        bundle = self.build_bundle(data={'pk': kwargs['pk']}, request=request)
        obj = self.cached_obj_get(bundle=bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return HttpGone()
    except MultipleObjectsReturned:
        return HttpMultipleChoices("More than one resource is found at this URI.")

    attack_resource = AttackResource()
    return attack_resource.get_detail(request, id=obj.pk)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create nested resources by overriding a override_urls function in your resources.
One way to do this can be found in tastypie [**documentation**](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#nested-resources). It`s based on creation of a custom function in your resource that will get all children, and you need to write this for every resource.

If this is not work well for you then there  other way to do it.A more generic way and it will work for all nested resources without writing any additional functions. It can be found on this [**gist**](https://gist.github.com/809993).

Comment: I've been trying to do this with the cookbook and now with the gist. I'm at a loss. Updating the question with more info.